# Qt - Get response from function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a Qt application that need to send a request to server and get the response.
I have a class A (MainWindow) that handle the GUI, and a class B(Requester ) that handle the http request.

When I call Connector from main func - I get the response. But when I try to hit the button I can't get the response -> the connect trigger never emits.

So I sniff my network with Wireshark and detect that when I hit the button the request send and I my computer gets the response - but the Signal never emits :(

```
class MainWidget : public QWidget {
    QLineEdit *url_input = new QLineEdit(this);
    QToolBar *tool_bar = new QToolBar;

public:
    MainWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setToolBar();
    void startRequest();
};

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    setToolBar();
    // SOME_CODE
}

void MainWidget::setToolBar() {
    QPixmap list_png("list.png");

    QAction *list = tool_bar->addAction(QIcon(list_png), "list");
    tool_bar->addSeparator();

    connect(list, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWidget::startRequest);
}

void MainWidget::startRequest () {
    Request req; 
    req.Connector(); // **Here it's NOT working**
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWidget widget;

    Request req;
    req.Connector(); // **Here is perfectly working**

    widget.setGeometry(700, 450, 500, 250);
    widget.setWindowTitle("App GUI");
    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Could someone tell me why it's happend ?
I'm using Qt-5.10.0
Thanx in advance :)

Comment: @TheDude Now it's okay ?

Comment: That's better, yes.

Comment: @TheDude Good, Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable exists only when its context exists, in the case of the `Request` that is in the `main` this will exist forever because the `main` exists while the application exists, instead the `Request` of `startRequest()` will only exist while that function is called and at the end the object will be eliminated, so after that there will be no object that issued it. One possible solution is to create a `Request` pointer since you are working directly with the memory, but it is your duty to remove it from memory later.

```
void MainWidget::startRequest () {
    Request *req = new Request; 
    req->Connector(); 
}
```

Comment: some more technical terms like "automatic storage duration" and "scope" instead of "context" could help here for further clarification

Comment: @PeterT I would appreciate if you edit my answer if you think that you make it more readable :D